# Android SQLite insert statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I have recently started developing some app in Android studio. I am trying to understand SQLite database. I am trying to create a simple table and inserting into it. My application crashes after running the following code.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);                      
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student "+  " (name VARCHAR, number VARCHAR );");
String name = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameField)).getText().toString();
String num = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberField)).getText().toString();
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('"+name+"','"+num+"');");
```

Comment: Post your logcat and code properly first...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

Create table in onCreate() method:

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE student(name text,num text)";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

you have to use the insert() method instead of execSQL?

```
ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
insertValues.put("name ", name);
insertValues.put("num", num);
db.insert("student", null, insertValues);
```